# On the integration to the surface and volume of a right cone

Tags: calculus, geometry

Consider the following figure:

[image: cone for the integration problem]

We want to assume that $\theta=\pi/4$ so that in the figure
    $r=h$, and $R=H$. That is the angle between the cone side and its axis
    is 45 degrees. Let us find the surface along the side of  the cone. 
    A naive method would be to integrate along the vertical line where we know that each 
    anulus  is a circle, and
    so we can do the following:

\begin{eqnarray*}
  S = \int_0^H (2 \pi r) dr
\end{eqnarray*}
    (see that $r=h$). Then we find that

\begin{eqnarray*}
    S = \pi R^2.
\end{eqnarray*}
    The side area of the cone is equal to to the area of the circle in the bottom.
    We know this cannot be true since the cone area would be that of the circle in the 
    bottom. But the cone is like the circle being stretched by (think of making
    the circle into the cone by pulling it up while having the center pined to
    the origin) $\sqrt{2}$ (the ratio of the 45 degrees diagonal  and the 
    side of a square).  We see in the Figure how the ring along the cone is squeezed
    when projected in the circle. That is, the true area of the side of the cone
    is $S = \sqrt{2} \pi R^2$. This could have been found directly by doing the
    integral
\begin{eqnarray*}
  S = \int_0^H (2 \pi r) ds
\end{eqnarray*}
    where $s$ the side and we know that $s=\sqrt{2}h$, and so $ds = \sqrt{2} h$.

My question is the following. Let us suppose we want to find the volume of
    the cone. Then we can integrate discs along the vertical. Each disc
    has an area of $\pi r^2$, and the volume would be given by

\begin{eqnarray*}
  V = \int_0^H \pi r^2 dh = \frac{\pi H^3}{3}= \frac{(\pi R^2) H}{3}.
\end{eqnarray*}
    (again see that $r=h$).
    Area of the base times height ``$H$'' divided by 3. Here the formula
    is correct. Why we do not need to consider the stretching of the circles
    when projected along the horizontal plane here? Why the $\sqrt{2}$ is
    not involved?  Should not we keep the scaling when going to higher dimensions?
    The angle $\theta=\pi/4$ is to make a simple illustration but the idea remains
    for any other angle $0 < \theta < \pi/2$.

Comment: Look at this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1367697/alternative-proof-of-lateral-surface-area-of-a-conical-frustum/1368702#1368702

Comment: @Arentino : Thanks for the tip. Your answer relates to the first part of my question which I understand. I do not understand why for the volume you do not get a factor such as your $\sqrt{1+m^2}$ factor.

Comment: For the volume you don't have that factor because the ratio between the volume of the real disc (a cone frustum) and the volume of the approximating disc (a cylinder) tends to 1 when disc height tends to 0.