# Lateral area of a cone - derivation using integrals

Tags: calculus, geometry

I'm trying to derive the formula for lateral area of a cone, $A = \pi r L$ by summing the circumferences of circles of decreasing radius that make up the cone.

[image: cone]

(image source: https://brilliant.org/wiki/surface-area-of-a-cone/)

The radius $r_1$ of a circle (a "disk") at height *x* from the bottom is given by a formula that we obtain from similar triangles:
$$\frac{r_1}{h-x} = \frac{r}{h}$$
$$r_1 = \frac{h-x}{h}r$$
$$r_1 = \left(1-\frac{x}{h}\right)r$$
therefore the circumference of that same circle is given by the function
$$f(x) = 2r \pi \left(1-\frac{x}{h}\right)$$
[Solving the integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+2*r*pi*%281-x%2Fh%29+dx+from+0+to+h) yields the formula $\pi h r$ which is incorrect. Where did I make a mistake?
[image: wolfram alpha integral]

Comment: You have to integrate the areas of infinitesimal truncated cones, not the perimeters of circles.

Comment: Here is what I mean: your $f(x)dx$ is the lateral area of an infinitesimal cylinder, not the lateral area of a truncated cone.

Comment: To salvage the mistake you are doing you can consider the infinitesimal area as $f(x)\sqrt{dx^2 + dr_1^2} =  f(x)\sqrt{1 + (dr_1/dx)^2}dx$. This is still not accurate for the infinitesimal area but error would be samll enough to approach zero when you take limit of sum.

Comment: @GReyes how would I use the formula for area of a truncated cone while looking for a formula for area of a regular cone, if a formula for area of truncated cone is just the formula for a regular cone subtracted

Comment: You are considering your cone as made of infinitesimally thin truncated cones, since you are slicing it by horizontal planes between $x$ and $x+dx$.

Comment: Tony Pizza’s comment is correct. The area of a truncated cone is the perimeter of the mid-circle by the length of the slant altitude

Comment: This might be of help: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1368702/255730

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You may also calculate like this: The surface is construct of infinite tiangles with base $GG'=dc$ and height  $D'H=l$, So:

$ds=\frac 12 l\cdot dc$. and we have:

$dc=r\cdot d{\alpha}$

and lateral surface is:

$$S=\int^{2\pi}_0\frac 12 l\cdot r d{\alpha}=\frac 12 l\big[\alpha\big]^{2\pi}_0= \pi \cdot rl$$

or in term of $r$ and $h$:

$$S=\pi r \sqrt {r^2+h^2}$$